# Auto rotate fullscreen video in android

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview

I am a newbie, and I am trying to make a simple application that can play video from url. I am able to play video successfully in my app, but I want it auto rotate,hide actionbar title and fullscreen when I click button fullscreen.

This is my **manifest**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="htantruc.videotest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <activity android:name=".video"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VideoViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and my **xml**:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".VideoViewActivity"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActivityThemeNoActionBar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <com.github.rtoshiro.view.video.FullscreenVideoLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the getWidth and getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

How to set width and height

```
videoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
```

Call same code in your activity and `onConfigurationChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

1-Try this for Auto-Rotate - add these to Manifest :

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: Thank you, but this don't worked for me, I want it will rotate when click a button

Answer (score 0):

Please implement your fullscreen button click as below:

```
 public void onFullScreenClick(View v)
 {
     getActionbar().hide();
     getActionbar().show();


     //doesn't work then try
     //getSupportActionBar().hide();
     //getSupportActionBar().show();

     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

     // For Landscape above line and For Portrait find Below
     //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 }
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add line

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest file

Hope this will work